# Change url when manually scrolled to an anchor?

Tags: javascript, jquery

By Default, if I have anchors in my website, then the URL on the address bar is changed, when I click on a link (ie. www.mysite.com/#anchor)

Is it possible to change the URL in the address bar instantly when I scroll to an anchor? Or have a long document with multiple anchors and the url changes on address bar, when I hit a new anchor?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Try using this jquery plugin: [Scrollorama](http://johnpolacek.github.com/scrollorama/). It has tons of cool features and you can use `window.location.hash` to update your browsers hash.

Alternatively, you can add a "scroll" event to check when an anchor is reached.

Here is a working fiddle to illustrate the event: http://jsfiddle.net/gugahoi/2ZjWP/8/
Example:

```
$(function () {
    var currentHash = "#initial_hash"
    $(document).scroll(function () {
        $('.anchor_tags').each(function () {
            var top = window.pageYOffset;
            var distance = top - $(this).offset().top;
            var hash = $(this).attr('href');
            // 30 is an arbitrary padding choice, 
            // if you want a precise check then use distance===0
            if (distance < 30 && distance > -30 && currentHash != hash) {
                window.location.hash = (hash);
                currentHash = hash;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Amazing! Using a forked version of this for my project. However, we realised that using this caused a 'scroll jump' everytime the hash was changed. So, we used historyAPI as it fixed our problem. 

           if(history.pushState) {
               history.pushState(null, null, "#"+hash);
           }
           else {
               window.location.hash = '#myhash';
           }

Comment: Link doesn't work anymore, project updated, new version here: https://scrollmagic.io/

Answer (score 4):

you can use HTML 5 pushstate to change the URL in the address bar

window.history.pushstate

---

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history
2. [How can I use window.history.pushState 'safely'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5030564/how-can-i-use-window-history-pushstate-safely)

Comment: location.hash is more convenient

Comment: You should include salient portions in your answer; links have a bad habit of breaking on the internet (and yes, I know link rot is a pet peeve of Tim BL).

Answer (score 4):

Plain js version
While researching how to update the URL based off positions of HTML section elements on the screen, I kept finding this thread so I hope this is a good place to post this.

This function loops over the HTML section elements.

```
        function updateFragId() {
        var len = sections.length;
          for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            var id = sections[i].id;
```

Collects the Y scroll position relative to the viewport.

```
            var rect = sections[i].getBoundingClientRect().y;
```

convert the two arrays into an object

```
            var pageData = {id:id, rect:rect};
```

set a range for the code to trigger in between. Here it will trigger when the top of the section element is between -200px to 400px

```
            if (pageData.rect > -200 && pageData.rect < 400) {
```

only run once by making sure the pageData.id and location.hash dont already match. This stops it from flooding your browser with events.

```
        if (pageData.rect > -100 && pageData.rect < 100) {
            if (pageData.id !== location.hash.substr(1)) {
                fragmentId = pageData.id;
                setActiveLink(fragmentId);
              } else {
                return;
            }
          }
        }
      }

    window.addEventListener('scroll', updateFragId);
```

I use a debouncer on this block of code with another block to set the active link. But this is just how to track the # anchors.

Comment: Code-only answers are generally frowned upon on this site. Could you please edit your answer to include some comments or explanation of your code? Explanations should answer questions like: What does it do? How does it do it? Where does it go? How does it solve OP's problem?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Updated.

Answer (score 2):

1. Bind a handler to [jquery scroll event](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/).
2. Check if an anchor is currently visible on-screen with [this jquery
   script](http://benpickles.github.com/onScreen/).
3. Use pushstate or set location (probably will cause jumps)

Answer (score 2):

You can bind to the jQuery scroll event (http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) and on each call of the callback called, check how far on the document the user has scrolled by checking this value: .scrollTop (http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) and set the anchor by manipulating te location.hash object (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp).

It would be something like this:

```
// Checks if the passed element is visible on the screen after scrolling
// source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling
function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
  var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

  var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
  var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

  return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}

$('#document').scroll(function(e) {
  var anchors = $('.anchor');
  for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; ++i) {
    if (isScrolledIntoView(anchors[i])){
      var href = $(anchors[i]).attr('href');
      location.hash = href.slice(href.indexOf('#') + 1);
      break;
    }
  }
});
```

You could be more precise, if you sort the anchors after selecting them, so that the first visible anchor will be set always.

Comment: Hi george, thanks for sharing this. Could you please post an example html markup that works with the code above?

Comment: Sure. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/7d5qU/10/. It should work, but I couldn't manage to prove it, since jsfiddle hides the inner url...

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to do something like this. Not tried in action

```
var myElements = $("div.anchor"); // You target anchors
$(window).scroll(function(e) {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    myElements.each(function(el,i) {
        if ($(this).offset().top > scrollTop && $(myElements[i+1]).offset().top < scrollTop) {
             location.hash = this.id;
        }
    });
});
```