# change url while scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, try-catch

I am using jQuery to change the URL hash when I click on the navigation button. But when I scroll using the mouse wheel the URL won't change. How can I do that?
How can it be done using

```
window.history.pushState(“object or string”, “Title”, “/new-url”);
```

I am not able to understand it. Please help
my javascript code

```
$j(document).ready(function () {
    $j("#start1").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var section = this.href,
            sectionClean = section.substring(section.indexOf("#"));

        $j("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: $j(sectionClean).offset().top
        }, 1000, function () {
            window.location.hash = sectionClean;
        });
    });
});
$j(document).ready(function () {
    $j("#start2").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var section = this.href,
            sectionClean = section.substring(section.indexOf("#"));

        $j("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: $j(sectionClean).offset().top
        }, 1000, function () {
            window.location.hash = sectionClean;
        });
    });
});
```

and html code is

```
<a href="#home" id="start1"style="text-decoration:none;position:absolute;right:450px;top:37px;font-weight:bold;color:white;font-size:15px;z-index:200;transition:0.5s"  onmouseover="big(this)" onmouseout="small(this)"><span >HOME</span></a>
<span><a href="#products" id="start2" style="text-decoration:none;position:absolute;right:250px;top:37px;font-weight:bold;color:white;font-size:15px;transition:0.5s" onmouseover="big(this)" onmouseout="small(this)">PRODUCTS & SERVICES</a></span>
```

Comment: How are your navigation button?

Comment: i am editted the question please see

Comment: You said you want to do something when user scrolls page, but where is your code responsible for processing [onscroll event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onscroll.asp)?

Comment: @sergey Actually on my page i have that effect of changing url when link clicked but i am unable to do this while scrolling. So i wanted to know how it can be done as i don't know about this

Comment: This fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/prjau477/ shows how to process `onscroll` event using jQuery

Comment: You may find the the answers to this question helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14660580/change-url-when-manually-scrolled-to-an-anchor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some code that may help you - it listens for the `scroll` event, and checks to see if any of the `anchor` elements are in the viewport. If they are, the URL hash is updated with `window.history.pushState`.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Scrolling URL Hash</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Webpage for xxxx">
  <style>
    body {
      height: 2000px;
    }
    a > div {
      min-height: 500px;
    }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body> 
  <a href="#anchor1" id="anchor1" class="anchor"><div>ANCHOR 1</div></a>
  <a href="#anchor2" id="anchor2" class="anchor"><div>ANCHOR 2</div></a>
  <a href="#anchor3" id="anchor3" class="anchor"><div>ANCHOR 3</div></a>
  <a href="#anchor4" id="anchor4" class="anchor"><div>ANCHOR 4</div></a>
  <a href="#anchor5" id="anchor5" class="anchor"><div>ANCHOR 5</div></a>
  <a href="#anchor6" id="anchor6" class="anchor"><div>ANCHOR 6</div></a>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    // stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-to-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport
    function isElementInViewport (el) {
      //special bonus for those using jQuery
      if (typeof jQuery === "function" && el instanceof jQuery) {
        el = el[0];
      }
      var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
      return (
        rect.top >= 0 &&
        rect.left >= 0 &&
        rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) && /*or $(window).height() */
        rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth) /*or $(window).width() */
      );
    }
    // click-to-scroll behavior
    $(".anchor").click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var section = this.href;
      var sectionClean = section.substring(section.indexOf("#"));
      $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: $(sectionClean).offset().top
      }, 1000, function () {
        window.location.hash = sectionClean;
      });
    });
    // listen for the scroll event
    $(document).on("scroll", function() {
      console.log("onscroll event fired...");
      // check if the anchor elements are visible
      $(".anchor").each(function (idx, el) {
        if ( isElementInViewport(el) ) {
          // update the URL hash
          if (window.history.pushState) {
            var urlHash = "#" + $(el).attr("id");
            window.history.pushState(null, null, urlHash);
          }
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: sometimes url changes and sometimes not bu using it

Comment: The function `isElementInViewport` checks to see if the *entire* element is visible. If it's not (for example, if your browser window is smaller than the element) then the URL won't change.

Comment: You could work around this by making the anchor elements as small as possible (instead of `min-height: 500px`, as in this case) or by modifying `isElementInViewport`.

Comment: when i scroll fast then the url don't change but when i scroll slowly then it is working '

Comment: I'm not sure what's happening there - I can't reproduce it by scrolling fast. All I can think of is that the entire element might not be rendered to the viewport when scrolling quickly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use waypoint.js.
http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/guides/getting-started/

Here is an example code from the page, throw a new hash when the waypoint is reached.

```
var waypoint = new Waypoint({ element: document.getElementById('element-waypoint'), handler: function(direction) { notify(this.element.id + ' triggers at ' + this.triggerPoint) }, offset: '75%' })
```