# Change URL on scroll to anchor and then remove when reach the top

Tags: html, jquery, anchor

[I have found a great piece of code](https://gist.github.com/JoeSz/48743c0d898bf6e6735064cc3d564a9d) that allows the URL in the menu bar to change when you scroll to an anchor on the page.

Code below:

```
 function isElementInViewport (el) {
      //special bonus for those using jQuery
      if (typeof jQuery === "function" && el instanceof jQuery) {
        el = el[0];
      }
      var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
      return (
        rect.top >= 0 &&
        rect.left >= 0 &&
        rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) && /*or $(window).height() */
        rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth) /*or $(window).width() */
      );
    }
    // click-to-scroll behavior
    $(".anchor").click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var section = this.href;
      var sectionClean = section.substring(section.indexOf("#"));
      $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: $(sectionClean).offset().top
      }, 1000, function () {
        window.location.hash = sectionClean;
      });
    });
    // listen for the scroll event
    $(document).on("scroll", function() {
      console.log("onscroll event fired...");
      // check if the anchor elements are visible
      $(".anchor").each(function (idx, el) {
        if ( isElementInViewport(el) ) {
          // update the URL hash
          if (window.history.pushState) {
            var urlHash = "#" + $(el).attr("id");
            window.history.pushState(null, null, urlHash);
          }
        }
      });
    });
```

The only issue is that the page started with just a plain URL such as https://sample.com, and when you scroll down it changes to https://sample.com/#hash however this code doesn't remove these added hashes from the URL when you return to the top.

I'd like to be able to alter this code to remove the hash if the anchor is out of the viewport or no anchor is visible at all.

I've tried to add some else statements after the if isElementInViewport but so far havent been able to get anything to work.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this condition:

```js
if ( $(window).scrollTop() == 0 ) {
    window.history.pushState(null, null, window.location.pathname);
} else {
    window.history.pushState(null, null, urlHash);
}
```

so if you're at the very top hash will be cleared. Hope it's something you wanted to achieve.

EDIT (added full script with changes):

```js
// Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30734552/change-url-while-scrolling
// stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-to-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport
function isElementInViewport(el) {
    //special bonus for those using jQuery
    if (typeof jQuery === "function" && el instanceof jQuery) {
        el = el[0];
    }
    var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    return (
        rect.top >= 0 &&
        rect.left >= 0 &&
        rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) && /*or $(window).height() */
        rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth) /*or $(window).width() */
    );
}
// click-to-scroll behavior
$(".anchor").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var section = this.href;
    var sectionClean = section.substring(section.indexOf("#"));
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: $(sectionClean).offset().top
    }, 1000, function () {
        window.location.hash = sectionClean;
    });
});
// listen for the scroll event
$(document).on("scroll", function () {
    console.log("onscroll event fired...");
    // check if the anchor elements are visible
    $(".anchor").each(function (idx, el) {
        if (isElementInViewport(el)) {
            // update the URL hash
            if (window.history.pushState) {
                var urlHash = "#" + $(el).attr("id");
                if ($(window).scrollTop() == 0) {
                    window.history.pushState(null, null, window.location.pathname);
                } else {
                    window.history.pushState(null, null, urlHash);
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply! Where do I add this? I just tried adding it to the bottom but it bugged out the code a little. I then tried to put the isElementInViewport and it didn't do anything. Really appreciate the help

Comment: I added full script for clarification.

Comment: I really appreciate the help but it doesnt seem to work, when i get to the top it still remains with an anchor hashtag in the URL

Comment: That's weird because i have no problem with this code. Maybe create new file and paste this content into it: https://pastebin.com/raw/wpYF9hVr then save as `.html` and open in browser.

Comment: Thank you! I had to debug a few things on the live site before it worked due to other things in the way - this code you've provided is perfect!