# Angular2 Router: add hashtag to url

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-seed

I'm using Angular2 Seed application, and you can find it in the [official repo](https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed). As you can see, here we have angular2/router imported, and we're using it to create the basic routing of the application.

```
import {Component, ViewEncapsulation} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {
  RouteConfig,
  ROUTER_DIRECTIVES
} from 'angular2/router';
...
@RouteConfig([
  { path: '/', component: HomeCmp, as: 'Home' },
  { path: '/about', component: AboutCmp, as: 'About' }
])
export class AppCmp {}
```

My question is: **how can I configure router to add hashtag in my url, to make it looks like: localhost:5555/#/about**. Is there any beautiful and easy way to make it? (as earlier with $locationProvider)

I know it's bizarre, but I used to love this hashtag in url, and my apache-config also used to love it. Of course, I can change my httpd.conf file, very easy and properly, but I really want to figure out, how to simply add hashtag, with Angular2 Router.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your application startup file, you need to provide locationstrategy while calling bootstrap,

```
import {LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from 'angular2/router';

class MyDemoApp {
    //your code
}

bootstrap(MyDemoApp,[provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy})]);
```

Comment: It seems it is located under '@angular/common' now. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/HashLocationStrategy-class.html

Answer (score 1):

For anyone with the same problem, but not using Angular Seed:

```
navigateToSomeLocation(location: string){
  window.location.href = "#" + location;
}
```

if you use Angular Material and you want to subscribe to the scroll event to change the url (like here: https://material.io/design/navigation/understanding-navigation.html#), subscribe to the ScrollDispatcher:

```
constructor(public scrollDispatcher: ScrollDispatcher) {
  this.scrollingSubscription = this.scrollDispatcher.scrolled()
      .subscribe((data: CdkScrollable) => {
        console.log(window.pageYOffset);

  });
}
```

and then check the if the user is scrolling over the anchor:

```
elem = document.getElementById('someHTMLElement') as HTMLElement;
distance = elem.getBoundingClientRect().top;

if (distance < 30 && distance > -30) {
    this.navigateToSomeLocation(elem.id);
  }
```

for reference see: [Change url when manually scrolled to an anchor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14660580/change-url-when-manually-scrolled-to-an-anchor)