# Append hashtag for link in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I am beginner for angular 2 and i want to append hashtag at end of URL just like below :

```
http://localhost:4200/detail#one
```

I have tried this :

```
<a [routerLink]="['/detail#one']" >Link</a>
```

but # is being converted to '%23' :

```
http://localhost:4200/detail%23one
```

How can we do this in angular 2 to get URL like :

```
http://localhost:4200/detail#one
```

Thanks

Comment: Why you want that `#`. Please mentioned and also mention what you have done for that.

Comment: @gsamaras please see the updated question. I want to scroll down at particular div of the page

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33226286/angular2-router-add-hashtag-to-url) help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use JavaScript's **encodeURI** function to keep the hashtag as a hashtag.  This would require you to set up a variable in the class which that component belongs to.

`const detailOneHash = encodeURI('#one');`

In the `routerLink`, add the variable to the `fragment` attribute:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/detail']" attr.fragment="{{detailOneHash}}">Link</a>
```

You can find more information about `routerLink` in [Angular's API](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink).