# Getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined" on javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using some code I found at [Change url when manually scrolled to an id even scrolling to top?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37964541/11081472).

It works as intended, but Chrome's Console is giving me an error message, "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined", for the line:

```
var currentElementTop = $(blocksArr[i]).offset().top;
```

I'd like to get rid of this error, so what do I need to change/add?

(BTW, I would post this question as a comment on the original post, but for some reason I need a reputation of 50...?)

Here's the code in action:

```js
$(function () {
  var currentHash = "#";
  var blocksArr = $('.anchor');

  $(document).scroll(function () {
     var currentTop = window.pageYOffset/1;
     for (var i=0; blocksArr.length; i++){
         var currentElementTop = $(blocksArr[i]).offset().top;
         var hash = $(blocksArr[i]).attr('id');
         if (currentElementTop < currentTop && currentTop < currentElementTop + $(blocksArr[i]).height() && currentHash!=hash){
                if(history.pushState) {
                history.pushState(null, null, '#'+hash);
        }
        else {
            location.hash = '#'+hash;
        }
                currentHash = hash;
         }

     }

  });
});
```

```css
   html, body {
 height: 100%;
 min-height: 100%;
 font-size: 100%;
 text-shadow:none;
 margin: 0;
 }
 
    div {
      min-height: 100%;
   font-size: 100px;
   padding: 25px 50px;
    }
 
 .hero {
    line-height: 30vh;
    padding: 35vh 10vh;
    max-height: 100vh;
    min-height: auto;
    text-align: center;
 }
 
 .red {
 background: orangered;
 color: white;
 }
 
 .white {
 background: ghostwhite;
 color: black;
 }
 
 .blue {
 background: blue;
 color: white;
 }
```

```html
<div id="Hero" class="anchor red hero">Hero</div>
  <div id="About" class="anchor white">About</div>
  <div id="What" class="anchor blue">What</div>
  <div id="Why" class="anchor white">Why</div>
  <div id="Contact" class="anchor red">Contact</div>
  
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: There are cases where `.offset()` will not return an object having the member `top`. You need to check this before attempting to use it.

Comment: @prodigitalson We've established that the case here is `$(null).offset()` returns undefined - can you provided other "cases"?

Comment: @freedomn-m: according to the docs, if the element has `display:none`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your for statement is wrong.

```
for (var i=0; blocksArr.length; i++){
```

So if you loop makes it to the end of the array it keeps going and it will not have an element. So when you get to `i = blocksArr.length`, that is when the error occurs. jQuery is doing `$(undefined).offset().top` and you get the error.

```
for (var i=0; i < blocksArr.length; i++){
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it. :-D

Answer (score 0):

You could try use `each`:

```
$('.anchor').each((index, obj) => {
    var currentElementTop = $(obj).offset().top;

    var hash = $(obj).attr('id');
    if (currentElementTop < currentTop && currentTop < currentElementTop + $(obj).height() && currentHash!=hash){
        if(history.pushState) {
            history.pushState(null, null, '#'+hash);
        } else {
            location.hash = '#'+hash;
        }
        currentHash = hash
     }
});
```

Comment: It will fix the issue, but did not explain the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
for (var i=0; blocksArr.length; i++){
```

should be

```
for (var i=0; i<blocksArr.length; i++){
```

You're looping from 0 until *truthy* (blocksArr.length == true) - which it always is.  You don't get an infinite loop because it crashes out on

```
blocksArr[blocksArr.length]
```

(as array's are 0 based, this should stop at `blocksArr[blocksArr.length-1]`)

If you were to catch/ignore this, your code would get stuck in an infinite loop.

```js
$(function () {
  var currentHash = "#";
  var blocksArr = $('.anchor');

  $(document).scroll(function () {
     var currentTop = window.pageYOffset/1;
     
     for (var i=0; i<blocksArr.length; i++){
     
         var currentElementTop = $(blocksArr[i]).offset().top;
         var hash = $(blocksArr[i]).attr('id');
         if (currentElementTop < currentTop && currentTop < currentElementTop + $(blocksArr[i]).height() && currentHash!=hash){
                if(history.pushState) {
                history.pushState(null, null, '#'+hash);
        }
        else {
            location.hash = '#'+hash;
        }
                currentHash = hash;
         }

     }

  });
});
```

```css
html, body {
 height: 100%;
 min-height: 100%;
 font-size: 100%;
 text-shadow:none;
 margin: 0;
 }
 
    div {
      min-height: 100%;
   font-size: 100px;
   padding: 25px 50px;
    }
 
 .hero {
    line-height: 30vh;
    padding: 35vh 10vh;
    max-height: 100vh;
    min-height: auto;
    text-align: center;
 }
 
 .red {
 background: orangered;
 color: white;
 }
 
 .white {
 background: ghostwhite;
 color: black;
 }
 
 .blue {
 background: blue;
 color: white;
 }
```

```html
<div id="Hero" class="anchor red hero">Hero</div>
  <div id="About" class="anchor white">About</div>
  <div id="What" class="anchor blue">What</div>
  <div id="Why" class="anchor white">Why</div>
  <div id="Contact" class="anchor red">Contact</div>
  
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You might want to wrap the offending line in a try-catch block.  If you are breaking on the error (which it doesn't sound like you are), this will prevent that.  Otherwise, this might give you a little bit more detail on what the error is.

Something along these lines:

```
try {
  var currentElementTop = $(blocksArr[i]).offset().top;
}
catch(err) {
  console.log(err.message);
}
```

Comment: And now it will crash as it goes into an infinite loop. :)

Comment: But at least you get a nice console log... full of `Cannot read property 'top' of undefined` :)