# Seamless url change

Tags: javascript, html, url, transition

How do sites like [this](http://www.e-types.com/) change urls seamlessly?

If you scroll on this link it animates a transition and the url changes from:

```
http://www.e-types.com/
```

to

```
http://www.e-types.com/work
```

And if you click the logo it transitions back without any flicker or loading time. Any ideas what method they're using?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14660580/change-url-when-manually-scrolled-to-an-anchor

Comment: Refer @HarshaW answer to accommodate your query please. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change url when manually scrolled to an anchor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14660580/change-url-when-manually-scrolled-to-an-anchor)

Comment: @HarshaW It's not the scrolling url change that I was wondering about, it's the seamless animation while a new url loads, for example when you click on these projects: http://www.buildinamsterdam.com/cases

Comment: pushState, most likely: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea behind is that there is only one page (single-page application).

The change in URL is handled by the History API, as mentionned in the comments :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

But it only changes the address, it does not actually load a full document. So the javascript can do any transition it wants on the content.

There is plenty of libraries that offer this feature.

More specificly, the linked site uses AngularJS.

You can find a complete example of ng-animate + router at this address:
https://github.com/cornflourblue/ng-animate-ui-router-example

Depending on what you need, you can use a simple scroll with:
https://github.com/oblador/angular-scroll

You can also do similar things with other popular tools:

- VueJS: https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/transitions.html
- React: https://github.com/maisano/react-router-transition

Comment: Or yet simpler using JS + jQuery

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I didn't find any plugin that handles these two aspects; if you have one, I would be glad to add it.