# $(this) inside React Component

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I am trying to change the url while scrolling the page.

I am using jQuery .scroll() for that. The problem is that `this` on `$(this)` grabs the context of the React component. How can I change this code to make it work?

```
import React from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';

class Main extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    $(() => {
      let currentId = 'about';

      $(document).scroll(() => {
        $('.path').each(() => {
          const top = window.pageYOffset;
          const distance = top - $(this).offset().top;
          const path = $(this).attr('id');

          if (distance < 50 && distance > -50 && currentId !== path) {
            window.history.pushState(null, null, '/' + path);
            currentId = path;
          }
       });
      });
     }); 
  }

 render() {
     return (
       <main role="main">
         <About />
         <Contact />
       </main>
     );
   }
 }


export default Main;
```

The error:
[image]

Just as a complement, I am following these 'helpers' and adapt them to my needs:

- The accepted answer for this question:
  [Change url when manually scrolled to an anchor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14660580/change-url-when-manually-scrolled-to-an-anchor)
- This jsfiddle: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gugahoi/2ZjWP/8)

Comment: You are right. It's a mistake. I will correct it.

Comment: Is the wrapping ` $(() => { //... }` in your `componentDidMount` the same as the regular jQuery `document.ready` function? If so, your code is never going to run since your component will mount after the `document.ready` event fires.

Comment: @mccambridge a document ready will execute immediately if it has already reached the point that the page has already loaded.

Comment: Just as a complement: I am following this jsFiddle and adapt it to my needs: http://jsfiddle.net/gugahoi/2ZjWP/8/

Comment: @mccambridge  http://jsfiddle.net/va2nwujs/

Comment: @mccambridge I removed the wrapper and the same error appears as before: TypeError: elem.getClientRects is not a function. Than it points to `const distance = top - $(this).offset().top;` where the execution blocks.

Comment: @Taplar my mistake. Been a while since I jQuery'd regularly ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use normal function when you need dynamic context

```
$('.path').each(function() {
          const top = window.pageYOffset;
          const distance = top - $(this).offset().top;
          const path = $(this).attr('id');

          if (distance < 50 && distance > -50 && currentId !== path) {
            window.history.pushState(null, null, '/' + path);
          }
       });
```

Comment: I will try it out. Thank you:)

Comment: It doesn't work unfortunately. I receive always the same error as before: TypeError: elem.getClientRects is not a function. Than it points to `const distance = top - $(this).offset().top;` where the execution blocks.

Comment: @Luca Fabbri I had to rollback your edit because it goes against my idea. `this` inside `$('.path').each` callback is dom element.

Answer (score 0):

So, **the solution is the accepted answer**. The problem had to do with the way I was adding the anonymous function as a parameter for the `.each()` method. Instead of `() => {...}`, use `function(){...}`.

```
$(() => {
      let currentPath = '';
      $(document).scroll(() => {
        $('.path').each(function () {
          const top = window.pageYOffset;
          const distance = top - $(this).offset().top;
          const path = $(this).attr('id');

          if (distance < 30 && distance > -30 && currentPath != path) {
            window.history.replaceState(`/${path}`, 'Title', `/${path}`);
            currentPath = path;
          }
        });
      });
    });
```

Comment: But this is exactly my answer. :)

Comment: Sorry! I didn't noticed :( I tested it just removing the wrapper around.