# Change url depending on content off site

Tags: javascript, html

I want the url to be changed depending of the content that is focused on the site. If I am reading a article and the header is called "economics" I want to add "#economics" as an anchor tag to the url so the users easy can copy the url to share a specific article.
Its kinda hard to explain so here is a site that have the scroll/url function that I am looking for: [WEBSITE](https://www.sydsvenskan.se/2018-08-16/sturup-utrymt-polis-pa-plats) (try to scroll down).

What is this called and how can i get started?

Comment: did you try any thing??

Comment: @iNullPointer Well i have some ideas ex: a js script that fires on scroll event that takes the closest <h1> tag with a specific class and adds the text to the url. But i want some more "understanding" before proceeding

Comment: This may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14660580/change-url-when-manually-scrolled-to-an-anchor

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger scroll with [Waypoint](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/) and add hash string to url.

For example:

```
var waypoint = new Waypoint({
  element: document.getElementById('economics'),
  handler: function(direction) {
    window.location.hash = '#economics';
  }
})
```

When other users come from the URL, you can get hash from url and scroll to element. You can do this with [jQuery scrollTop function](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/).

I hope, i could help you.