# How to implement loading new articles while scrolling down on the web page change urls in address bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, frontend, web-frontend

I am interesting in designing web page and I usually go to some websites to study their frontend features.

I recently visit REUTERS and realized that their site will load new articles while I am scrolling down. Meanwhile, the address bar will also update the url to the corresponding article.

I like this feature and want to know how to design. 
Here is [the link](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-global-markets/dollar-dips-global-stocks-inch-up-ahead-of-powell-speech-idUSKCN1L901U).

Can anyone teach me how to implement this feature?

Comment: You could use a jQuery plugin like this: https://jscroll.com/. Alternatively you can study the plugin's inner workings and build your own solution

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14660580/change-url-when-manually-scrolled-to-an-anchor